# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, api

It is showing the following error :
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

```
        axios.get(`http://localhost:4000/api/AMS/country`)
     {
           .then(response => {
             //In the below line I am getting the error
             const country_Claim_Type = response.data;
             console.log(country_Claim_Type);
             this.setState({ country_Claim_Type });
                 })
       }
```

I expected some json data but I am getting undefined in the console.

Comment: So when you console.log() out response what does it show/provide?

Comment: It shows only " undefined ". I think the data is getting null that is why It is showing undefined but I don't know why ?

Comment: The error mesage means that response is not defined, maybe  it is returning an error?

Comment: yes it is throwing the below error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

Comment: I resolved the  issue there was a silly mistake , the mistake was I forgot to put the return before axios.get

Answer (score 0):

I think your code structure isn't quite correct:

```
axios.get(`http://localost:4000/api/AMS/country`)
// You had an erroneous { here
  .then(response => {
    // Your console.log() on response here should show 'data'
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't returning anything because of that error was occuring. Added a return keyword just before axios.get.

```
 return axios.get(`http://localhost:4000/api/AMS/country`)
     {
           .then(response => {
             //In the below line I am getting the error
             const country_Claim_Type = response.data;
             console.log(country_Claim_Type);
             this.setState({ country_Claim_Type });
                 })
       }
```